# Delete row if any column contains conditional formatted red cell

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel sheet which I populate data with every week. Based on a long list of conditional formatting Excel gives me 3 columns of red cells as in attached example:

[image: Screenshot]

Can you please help me in automating the deletion of these red rows.

The report I am looking for is expected to have no red cells. So we need to delete the complete row if any cell has this conditional formatted red.

Comment: According to the following post, you might want to consider posting this on super user rather than stack overflow: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question. • Also I recommend decide by a condition on the value (the one you used for the conditional formatting) instead of by a condition on the format.